# Select record if exist in one table, else select from another

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement

I'm writing a report for quotes. The quote table have a copy to track the change history, so every time someone change the quote table the old values are salved in this history table.

I want to include a field in my report named Original Due Date, which will show what is the original due date for the quote. If there is a record in the history table, it should get the first due date from there. Otherwise it should get the due date from the original table.

Here is some sample of the records I have in my tables.

Table 1:

```
|ID | Order  | Due Date   |
|1  | C1234  | 15/01/2000 |
|2  | C1235  | 15/02/2000 |
|3  | C1236  | 15/03/2000 |
|4  | C1237  | 15/04/2000 |
```

History Table:

```
|ID | Order  | Due Date   |
|1  | C1234  | 02/01/2000 |
|2  | C1234  | 05/01/2000 |
|3  | C1236  | 05/03/2000 |
|4  | C1236  | 07/03/2000 |
```

Expected results:

```
|ID | Order  | Original Due Date   |
|1  | C1234  | 02/01/2000          |
|2  | C1235  | 15/02/2000          |
|3  | C1236  | 05/03/2000          |
|4  | C1237  | 15/04/2000          |
```

This is the code I've tried, which does not work because my subquery return more than 1 value.

```
 select case when exists (select 1 from quoteheader qh inner join quoteheaderhistory qhh on QH.QH_RecordID = QHH.QH_RecordID)
        then (select QHH.QH_RFQ_Date from quoteheader qh inner join quoteheaderhistory qhh on QH.QH_RecordID = QHH.QH_RecordID)
        else QH.QH_RFQ_Date
        end,
    * from quoteheader qh inner join quoteheaderhistory qhh
          on QH.QH_RecordID = QHH.QH_RecordID
```

Comment: You can do this with a `LEFT JOIN` on your tables, grouping them by `Table 1.ID, Table 1.Order`.  You just need to use `ISNULL` between two aggregate `MIN` functions.

Comment: Just updated the query I've tried.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
DECLARE @tblO TABLE(ID INT,[Order] VARCHAR(10),DueDate DATE);
INSERT INTO @tblO VALUES(1,'C1234','20000115'),(2,'C1235','20000215'),(3,'C1236','20000315'),(4,'C1237','20000415');

DECLARE @tblH TABLE(ID INT,[Order] VARCHAR(10),DueDate DATE);
INSERT INTO @tblH VALUES(1,'C1234','20000102'),(2,'C1234','20000105'),(3,'C1236','20000305'),(4,'C1236','20000307');

WITH MinHistoricalDates AS
(
    SELECT MIN(DueDate) AS MinHistDat,[order]
    FROM @tblH
    GROUP BY [order]
)
SELECT orig.ID 
      ,orig.[order]
      ,ISNULL(mhd.MinHistDat,orig.DueDate) AS DueDateResolved 
FROM @tblO AS orig
LEFT JOIN MinHistoricalDates AS mhd ON mhd.[order]=orig.[order]
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
select [Order],[DueDate] from quoteheader
where [Order] not in
(select [Order] from
(select [Order],MIN(DueDate) as DueDate
from quoteheaderhistory 
group by [Order]) a
)

union all

select [Order],MIN(DueDate) as DueDate
from quoteheaderhistory 
group by [Order]
```

although the `join` answer might work better for you, depending on your data

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I was talking about in my comment:

```
DECLARE @A TABLE ([ID] INT, [Order] CHAR(5), [DueDate] DATE)
DECLARE @H TABLE ([ID] INT, [Order] CHAR(5), [DueDate] DATE)

INSERT INTO @A VALUES
(1, 'C1234', '01/15/2000'), 
(2, 'C1235', '02/15/2000'), 
(3, 'C1236', '03/15/2000'), 
(4, 'C1237', '04/15/2000')

INSERT INTO @H VALUES
(1, 'C1234', '01/02/2000'),
(2, 'C1234', '01/05/2000'),
(3, 'C1236', '03/05/2000'),
(4, 'C1236', '03/07/2000')

SELECT
    [header].[ID],
    [header].[Order],
    [DueDate] = ISNULL(MIN([history].[DueDate]), MIN([header].[DueDate]))
FROM
    @A [header]
    LEFT JOIN @H [history] ON [header].[Order] = [history].[Order]
GROUP BY
    [header].ID, [header].[Order];
```

EDIT:  **Shnugo**'s answer has a better execution plan, though; go with that one.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could also do a `left join` and use windowed function version of `MIN` to achieve your result:

```
select distinct
     t1.id,
     t1.[order],
     COALESCE(min(ht.Due_Date) OVER (partition by t1.[order] order by t1.id)
    ,min(t1.due_date) OVER (partition by t1.[order] order by t1.id)) as Original Due Date  
from table1 t1
left join history_table ht on ht.[Order] = t1.[Order];
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/95800/7/0)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT _order, min(due_date) as due_date
FROM history JOIN table1 USING (_order)
GROUP BY _order
```

This solution ignores the id, but you can easily generate after getting appropiate values.

Comment: Your syntax is for mysql, that won't work in sqlserver.